# Track Items in Shopping Cart for Anlytic Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have looked at the suggested code for Shopping cart and I'm confused why I have to repeat twice the push item. Let's pretend I don't have two items. I have over two based let's say their search. Another question is do I have to get the INSERT_ITEM from my data extension name attribute and replace them?

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
   _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "MID"]);       
   _etmc.push(["trackCart", { “cart”: [
    {"item" : "INSERT_ITEM", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY" , "price" : "INSERT_PRICE" ,
            "unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" } ,
    {"item" : "INSERT_ITEM", "quantity":  "INSERT_QUANTITY" , "price" : "INSERT_PRICE" ,
            "unique_id" : "INSERT_UNIQUE_ID" } 
   ]}]);   
</script>
```